# Can not Logged In as an Admin In Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have  made an Admin Interface(A very simple Admin Interface).But if i want to login as an admin,i can not able to logged in as an admin though my username and password is absolutely right.

My Admin Controllers resides,

```
app/
 controller/
   Admin/
      AdminController.php
```

And My views resides

```
app/
 views/
   admin/
      Admin-login.blade.php
```

and i have created routes something like this

```
Route::get('admin',array(

    'as' => 'admin',
    'uses' =>'Admin\AdminController@AdminLogin'

));

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'),function(){


  //These Urls are Intended page after Admin Sign In
    Route::get('marriage-admin/',array(

         'as' => 'marriage-admin',
         'uses' => 'MarriageController@MarriageAdmin'
        ));

    Route::post('edit-marital-data',array('as' => 'edit-marital-data','uses' => 'MarriageController@EditMarritalStatus'));
    Route::post('searched-marital-data',array('as' => 'searched-marital-data','uses' => 'MarriageController@SearchMarriage'));

}

Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'),function(){

/* CSRF Protect*/
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'),function(){
   Route::post('admin-marriage',array(

               'as' => 'admin-marriage',
               'uses' => 'Admin\AdminController@AdminLoginPost'

            ));
 }
}
```

and this is my Admin Controller

```
<?php

namespace Admin;

class AdminController extends \BaseController{

public function AdminLogin(){
    return \View::make('admin.login');
}

public function AdminLoginPost(){



    $auth=\Auth::attempt(array(

      'username' => \Input::get('username'),
      'password' => \Input::get('password')
        ));

    if($auth){

        return \Redirect::intended('marriage-admin');

    }else{

        return \Redirect::route('admin')->with('global','The username or password you provided is wrong!');
    }
    return Rediret::route('admin')->with('global','Please Review Your Admin Database.');
}


}

?>
```

and i have also created a Admin.php model since i have a different table namely `admins` in my database.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Admin extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface       {



    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    /*public static function blood_search($blood_group){

        return static::where('blood_group','LIKE','%'.$blood_group.'%');
    } */



    protected $table = 'admins';

    protected $fillable=array
    (   'username',
        'password'

    );



    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;



}
```

in mention, **page after login** or you can say the dash bored of the `Admin` is taken from another controller namely **MarriageController**

Now if i try to logged in as an Admin.
 i am getting the message

```
The username or password you provided is wrong!
```

which i have set in my Admin Controller, if `auth` is fail.

So why i am getting this message though the `username` and `password` i am providing is absolutely right ?
now my question is,am i missing some configuration for `Admin`??

Comment: is your password hashed?

Comment: Is that the reason??,in mention i have manually created admin username and password in Php Myadmin and forgot to make the password hashed? @SushantAryal

Comment: Yes. Auth::attempt() automatically hash the password field. while creating a new user save the hashed password.

Comment: i have saved the password field as md5 manually .. but it still not woking .. giving the same message @SushantAryal

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't use md5 encryption. While creating a user you need to Hash password using laravel Hash::make()

```
User::create(array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
));
```

If you want to manually insert it to database then

```
return Hash::make('yourpass');
```

then paste the returned result.